# Discord.js member.user returns the member's ID surrounded by <>

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to create a command for a discord bot which lists all the members of the inputted role, I'm currently mapping the members to a variable as shown below:

`let roleMembs = message.guild.roles.cache.get(roleId).members.map(m=>m.user)`

It works for the most part but some of the members are outputted as <@320600141855981588> rather than their name, I'm not sure why this is and I'm not sure of a work around, any help would be appreciated, I will leave the rest of the code below

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')

module.exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {
    if (!message.member.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "-------------- SERVER STAFF --------------")) return message.reply("You must be part of the moderation team to use this command!")
    let roleReq = message.content.split(" ").slice(1)
    let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === roleReq.join(" "))

    if(typeof role === "undefined") return message.channel.send("You have input an invalid role! Please try again!")
    
    let roleId = role.id
    let roleMembs = message.guild.roles.cache.get(roleId).members.map(m=>m.user)

    let roleList = ""

    if(roleMembs.length > 25) {
        let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
       for(let i = 0; i < 25; i++){
          roleList = roleList.concat(`${roleMembs[i]}\n`)
        }

       let roleList2 = ""
       let roleList3 = ""

       let x = 0
       let y = 0

       while(x < 25){
          roleList2 = roleList2.concat(`${roleMembs[x+25]}\n`)
          x++
          if (typeof roleMembs[x+25] === "undefined"){
              break;
            }
        }
        if(roleMembs.length > 50){
            while(y < 25){
                roleList3 = roleList3.concat(`${roleMembs[y+50]}\n`)
                y++
                if (typeof roleMembs[y+50] === "undefined"){
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        embed.setAuthor(client.user.username, client.user.displayAvatarURL())
        embed.setTimestamp()
        embed.setTitle(`${roleMembs.length} Members with the ${roleReq.join(" ")} role:`)
        embed.setColor("#add8e6")
        embed.addField("‏‏‎ ‎", roleList, true)
        embed.addField("‏‏‎ ‎", roleList2, true)
        if(roleList3.length > 0) {
            embed.addField("‏‏‎ ‎", roleList3, true)
        }

        message.channel.send(embed)
    } else {
        roleMembs.forEach(member => {
            roleList = roleList.concat(`${member}\n`)  
        })
        let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        embed.setAuthor(client.user.username, client.user.displayAvatarURL())
        embed.setTimestamp()
        embed.setTitle(`${roleMembs.length} Members with the ${roleReq.join(" ")} role:`)
        embed.setColor("#add8e6")
        embed.addField(" ", roleList)
        message.channel.send(embed)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`<@ID>` is Discord markdown representing a user mention. In a regular message, they would show up as the clickable blue link you see when you mention a user. Sometimes in embeds they break.

If you want their name, then specify that by mapping to their name. Right now you're creating an array of just user objects and expecting it to spit out their name.

```
let roleMembs = message.guild.roles.cache.get(roleId).members.map(m=>m.user.username)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it's a shame that this is the case and I presume with no work around for what I assume is a bug other than swapping to only mapping their username which will probably be the case

Comment: @ADragonDood, perhaps I misunderstood. What bug? Are you wanting it to show up as a mention in the embed but it's not?

Comment: I'm wanting them to show up as mentions but as you said it sometimes breaks in embeds and displays them as <@320600141855981588> which isn't useful as it doesn't let the user click on the name and bring them to the persons profile

Comment: @ADragonDood There is no way for a bot dev to work around that limitation of the Discord client. There are two likely things happening: 1. You're trying to use mentions in invalid places (title, footer, some others, field values should always work though) or 2. the client viewing the mention doesn't have that user cached, so it shows up *blue* but also just as the ID instead of the username. You may find 2. acceptable, but the mobile and desktop clients display it differently, sometimes it might just be "@invalid-user". In the case of 1. there's nothing to do.